# Read data from Web Page and feed it in Excel

Tags: java, excel, apache, shell, selenium

Is there any way wherein I can read data from an Excel file(from a Column) change the I/P of the Column Value in a HTTPS URL and then fetch the value from the Web Page and feed the I/P corresponding to the Row in another column which can be used in Shell.
I have googled and found that we can use Selenium and Apache POI to read and write into the Excel however how do I read the data from the Web Page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use node.js to fetch data on the web.
then you use node module

https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel-export

to make it as an excel sheet or

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node_spreadsheet

Comment: Thanks Rex, let me give it a try